# Is there a lower limit in which question will appear sorted by votes?

Tags: support, questions

Specificly [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/do-imaginary-animals-dragons-unicorns-etc-exist-in-the-real-world) question is quite low (worst I ever seen on any SE site).  So I was curious as to how it stacked against other bad questions.  When I sorted the questions by votes and went to the last possible page, the lowest voted question was at -8 where the question in question (no pun inteded) does not even show.  So, I just wondering if there's a lower limit in which questions are allowed to be shown?

Comment: I'd expect that page to filter out closed and deleted questions, but am not sure it does.

Comment: This one was closed but still shows http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10515/im-trying-to-track-down-a-novel-with-the-protagonist-visiting-a-reptilian-cro

Comment: Wait you said closed **AND** deleted..

Comment: As in, it would filter the set of closed questions.  It would also filter the set of deleted questions.

Answer (score 1):

On the front page, questions with a score of -4 and lower are not shown (the threshold is -8 on the meta site). All other question lists and search results show all posts regardless of score or closed status (unless your search takes these criteria into account). Deleted questions are never shown in any question list (only ♦moderators can see lists of deleted questions, and only by explicit request).

I see [the imaginary animals question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19245/do-imaginary-animals-dragons-unicorns-etc-exist-in-the-real-world) (+1/-20) as the 50th item on the [list of questions by vote](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes), which is strange: even if caching is going on, it should never have ranked that high. It should definitely be on the last page of that list. This may be a bug.